# Binding to service that was allready started by BroadcastReceiver creates new instance of service

Tags: android, service, process, ipc, broadcastreceiver

My Application uses a service that is started by a BOOT_COMPLETE BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
}
```

If, in an activity in my application, I try to bind to this service like this:

```
getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class), 
    _serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

a new Instance of the Service is created, allthough the first instance (created by the BroadcastReceiver) is still runnning. I logged the process IDs in the onCreate() method of the service and the first
service runs in a different process than the activity, the second instance is created in the same process as the activity. I tried setting a android:process argument in the service element of the manifest (both with leading : and without), but the result stays the same.

How do I bind to the service running in a different process instead of creating a new instance in the process the activity is running in?

Comment: why are the broadcast receiver and the activity running in different processes? is this necessary? you'll need AIDL and Inter Process Communication to do what you want.

Comment: @bigstones: It's not necessary for the broadcast receiver to run in different processes. It's just the way android sets things up by default apparently. How do I get the broadcast receiver and my main activity to run in the same process?

Comment: By default they *should* be running in the same process, AFAIK. Could you post the manifest?

Comment: @bigstones: I just changed the onBind() method of my service to return an aidl Binder instead of the Messenger I used before. Unfortunately the result is still the same.

Comment: @bigstones: manifest is [here](http://pastebin.com/H6p9jPn8) (slightly obfuscated).

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no experience with remote services. But a wild guess: isn't a dot missing in front of the broadcast receiver name?

Comment: @bigstones: Adding a . in front of the receiver name did not change the binding behaviour but according to the doc it should be a fully qualified name, so thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you, it does not.  Only one instance of a particular service component is ever active at a time, no matter how many times you start or bind to it.  Further, the service will only run in one process.  There is no way for it to run in different processes at different times.